# How to write the C++ DLL to call from LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I am a newbie to C++.I have a OpenCV C++ program, where the main function holds the list of images. I don't know how to create the C++ DLL to call from LabVIEW. As the LabVIEW given in office does not hold the vision pallette to call the image. So I need to call it from C++ DLL.

I have already read about NI instruments for conversion from C++ DLL to LabVIEW. I can understand how it works, but was not able to convert my thinking into coding.

As far as I understood, we can do this with two options:

1. Call library Function Node - manually specifying the variable depending on the functions. Header file is not needed.
2. Import shared Library Wizard - automatically takes the value from the file specified. Header file is needed for this.

Please help me out with the C++ DLL coding.

Comment: if you have no experience with dlls then [exploring this MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll?view=vs-2019) can be a good starting point. Also MSDN on [how to write a dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=vs-2019). Try these links and ask here what exact problems you face wihile cdoing the dll and exporting the functions.

Comment: [This article](https://machine-vision-adhiguna.blogspot.com/2010/10/combining-intel-opencv-and-ni-labview.html) is rather old but seems to describe what you want to do.